# Single line grid layout without grid-template-rows hack

Tags: html, css

I want to have a description list of items that, by using CSS grid, sits on a single row with a small variability to the width of each item and which hides each item as the width becomes too small to accommodate it.

So far I have come up with this which takes advantage of the `auto-fill` and `minmax` properties of `grid-template-columns`. Currently I have a bit of a hack to hide the items that won't fit. This is to set `overflow: hidden` but also to set a large number of `0`'s in `grid-template-rows` relative to the number of items in the list. If you remove `grid-template-rows` (and adjust the width) you'll see that you can see the overflowing items below.

Is there a way I can hide these overflowing elements without hardcoding a large number of `0`'s?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

dd {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a different solution, but use `repeat()` to save you from having to write out a bunch of `0`s.

So, use `grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(50, 0);` instead:

Alternatively, you could set a height to the `dl`, say `80px`, and use `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);`. This might not be an option if the content is variable in length/height.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5rem, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
}

dd {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Column name</dt>
    <dd>Example value</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's an improvement on several zeroes despite it still relying on a hard-coded value. It feels like I'm trying to get Grid to do something it wasn't really intended for and this is therefore the best solution.